# table generation issue in pdf generation using prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

```
    **I want to insert a table inside a parent table column.**

e.g :-
     <table>
      <tr>
        <th> Type </th>
        <th> Rate </th>
        <th> Duration </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td> Time <br/>
        <table>
           <tr>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th> Rate </th>
            <th> Duration </th>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td> Tom </td>
            <td> $100 </td>
            <td> 25 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> Tom1 </td>
            <td> $200 </td>
            <td> 20 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> Tom2 </td>
            <td> $300 </td>
            <td> 26 </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td> $1000</td>
      <td> 65 </td>
     </tr>
    </table>

 This is in html format . I want to display content in the same format in pdf using prawn.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [WickedPDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf). It's a PDF generation tool, but you write the HTML instead of learning new syntax etc. It also has the added bonus of being able to use Webkit syntax so html5 is consistant throughout

Comment: **Thanks for your suggestion.  Using prawn can i use html syntax in code. It identifies \n and \t in array. So it can identify table tag.**

Comment: In WickedPDF table header cannot get repeated in every page.   **act_as_flying_saucer** gem is good for generation of pdf and is based on java.  checkout this link **https://github.com/amardaxini/acts_as_flying_saucer**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to nest tables. Take a look at this question and answer: [prawn PDF: I need to generate nested tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379124/prawn-pdf-i-need-to-generate-nested-tables)