# Prawn pdf nested tables - can't find examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

I need to generate a document with nested tables in prawn pdf.

The most recent answer on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379124/prawn-pdf-i-need-to-generate-nested-tables) seems to indicate that I can do it like this:

```
(Prawn::Document.generate("subtable.pdf") do |pdf|
  subtable = pdf.make_table([["sub"],["table"]])
  pdf.table([[subtable,"original"]])
end
```

Unfortunatley doing that gives me the following error:

```
undefined method `size=' for #<Prawn::Table::Cell::Subtable:0xad3f1e4>
```

So checking the documentation I can see:
" You can use Prawn::Document#make_table to create a table for use as a subtable without immediately drawing it. See examples/table/bill.rb for a somewhat complex use of subtables. "
http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Table.html

Where can I see this examples/table/bill.rb? I've cloned the github repo, scoured the website and the manual but can't find these examples anywhere!

I know I'm missing something stupid. Does anyone know how do do nested tables correctly in prawn pdf and/or where the example files are located?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do:

gem which prawn

that would give you location of the prawn gem. It includes the examples dir. You can find table/bill.rb there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the [self documenting manual](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf) scroll down (or use ctrl-f) to go to "content_and_subtables" and you can see how they are used.

If you are still having trouble, post with a full trace of your error message and example of the code that you are using. This way we can debug the issue that you are having, and see if it something in your code or another problem altogether.